# Why am I getting Sasl errors when trying to authenticate to SES with Postifx?

Tags: email, smtp, sasl, amazon-ses

I am getting these two errors in my mail logs:

```
Aug 25 22:51:23 ns1 postfix/smtpd[246267]: warning: unknown[94.156.102.101]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Aug 25 22:55:22 ns1 postfix/smtp[247251]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
```

My server is running Webmin & Postfix. I have installed **libsasl2-modules**, but this was already installed and did not fix my issue. I am using **noplaintext, noanonymous** sasl authentication options.

Emails are not being delivered when using the Usermin webmail, and I am getting the following error in my Message Queue from Webmin:

```
delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[34.238.201.95]: no mechanism available
```

Here are Postfix settigns:

postconf -M output:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, ns1.fetz.dev, localhost.fetz.dev, , localhost
myhostname = mail.liliesjewels.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
resolve_dequoted_address = no
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_password_map
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sni_map
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: Please, put at least output of `postconf -M` and `postconf -n` into the question. Also note that web control panels are off topic here, so you better remove your webmin screenshots and references, else the question will be closed as off topic for certain.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov sorry abt that... updated the question.